# Tkinter Auto-update button state

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm building a very basic login system. I've almost completed it but I have one problem. I need to put a check in the 'register' button to be disabled untill it's entry meets some conditions. Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u35RW.jpg). Now, I'm aware that 'while loops' don't work in tkinter and why. This is just an example of what I'm trying to do! Any advice?

Comment: How do you validate the input of the entry? Why don't you set the state of the button to *normal* when all conditions are met? Where is the catch for you? Your question is open end and therefore not suitable for [so]. Please take a look at [ask].

Comment: I can't figure out how to keep cheking the entry untill the conditions are met, actually

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is create the register button, but set the state to disabled;

```
regbtn = ttk.Button(
    root, text="Register",
    command=do_register,
    state=tk.DISABLED
)
```

Later, you can treat `regbtn` like a dictionary and modify the state:

```
regbtn["state"] = "enabled"
```

To know *when* to enable the button, you need to *validate* the entry field.
(For example, my [resin-calculator](https://github.com/rsmith-nl/resin-calculator) program does input validation.)

But it short, it involves:

1. registering a validation function with the `tk.TK` object.
2. Setting the `Entry` widget to validate on a keypress.

For example, say we want to validate that an entry is a number.
To do that we create a function as shown below.
As a side-effect, this validation function enables/disables the register button depending on the validity of the data:

```
def is_number(data):
    """Validate the contents of an entry widget as a float."""
    try:
        float(data)
    except ValueError:
        regbtn["state"] = "disabled"
        return False
    regbtn["state"] = "enabled"
    return True
```

This function receives the contents of the entry widget and needs to return if that data is valid.

So, first we register that validation command;

```
    root = tk.TK()
    vcmd = root.register(is_number)
```

Then, when creating the button, we set it to call the validation whenever a key is pressed;

```
re = ttk.Entry(
    parent,
    validate="key",
    validatecommand=(vcmd, "%P")
)
```